# How can I take the values of selected nested aggrid table row?

Tags: python, grid, streamlit

Im trying to implement this aggrid nested table:

https://staggrid-examples.streamlit.app/ - “Nested Grid”

I can receive the selected rows of the main table this way:
grid_response.get(‘selected_rows’)

But the grid_response object does not update any fild when selecting an inner nested row.

Anyone knows?

Thank you

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible code?